# cakephp 2.x query url parameter are not passed true

Tags: url, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I have the folowing url: http://www.domain.com/admin/posts/list_media?rand=554&hash=&id=25
Cakephp genarates a Missing View error on the live server, the local server has no problems with this url.

The controller is loaded, but the problem occurs when the view is loaded. When I remove everything after the question mark in the url it works fine.

the params reach the the controller:

```
Array ( 
    [rand] => 554 
    [hash] => 
    [id] => 25 
)
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Many things can be the problem. Can you supply more information?

Comment: Please post the error details.  The view file that's missing is important.

Comment: When I specify the view in the script it works `this->render('admin_list_media','ajax');` Very strange.